# Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder'

Tags: eclipse, apache, build, velocity, webobjects

I get the following error when I am trying to clean and build the project in the eclipse. I am stuck at this point and couldn't move further. Can someone help me with this issue and let me know what caused this error and suggest a remedy. Thanks for your time.

WOLips Incremental Builder

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALActivationProxy'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALAppFoundation'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALAppServer'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALAsyncHandler'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALBusinessLogic'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALChinaMobile_CNKit'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALCypressKit'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALFatAlbert'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALFoundation'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALIcarusKit'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALJars'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALMailer'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALReportingBusinessLogic'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALSalesBusinessLogic'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALScheduler'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALStub'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALTestAdmin'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALTestBusinessLogic'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALTestDataService'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALTestStorefront'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALWorkflow'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ALZeppelinKit'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
Errors running builder 'WOLips Incremental Builder' on project 'ZngScheduler'.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.
The specified class for ResourceManager (org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl) does not implement org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManager; Velocity is not initialized correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do any of you paths contain a space character?

so if you create a new project, add no code and run it, you get this error?

Comment: I didn't see any space charecteristic. I get this error on the project's which I made few changes and I didn't get the error on building the project which is cloned from source

Comment: Do I understand that you have a project that is compiling fine, then you make a change and it no longer compiles?    So I ask again, if you create a new project, and compile it, does this work?